# How to fix python + virtualenv on latest Ubuntu 14.04 update?

Tags: 14.04, python, pip, virtualenv

Since latest `apt-get upgrade` on a 14.04 machine, all python scripts fail miserably.

The one-liner below triggers the problem:

```
$ python -c 'from pkg_resources import load_entry_point'
```

A more complete workflow:

`$ virtualenv --system-site-packages myenv
$ source myenv/bin/activate
$ pip install cryptography
...
Successfully installed cryptography idna pyasn1 setuptools enum34 ipaddress appdirs packaging
$ pip freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/log.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import colorama, pkg_resources
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2717, in <module>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 682, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2717, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2255, in activate
    list(map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt')))
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 1863, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 1832, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 246, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/home/milton/workdir/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=209485) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917534/pip-broken-on-ubuntu-14-4-after-package-upgrade#28919613) links may be related to this problem.

My list of installed packages

`dh-python
doxygen
fabric
ipython
libclone-perl
libfile-copy-recursive-perl
libpython-dev:amd64
libpython-stdlib:amd64
libpython2.7:amd64
libpython2.7-dev:amd64
libpython2.7-minimal:amd64
libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64
libpython3-stdlib:amd64
libpython3.4:amd64
libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64
libpyzy-1.0-0
liburcu1
pydb
pylint
python
python-apt
python-apt-common
python-aptdaemon
python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
python-astroid
python-autopilot
python-autopilot-trace
python-blockdiag
python-boto
python-bzrlib
python-cairo
python-chardet
python-chardet-whl
python-clang-3.6
python-cloudfiles
python-colorama
python-colorama-whl
python-commandnotfound
python-compizconfig
python-configobj
python-contextlib2
python-crypto
python-cups
python-cupshelpers
python-dateutil
python-dbus
python-dbus-dev
python-debian
python-debtagshw
python-decorator
python-defer
python-dev
python-dirspec
python-distlib
python-distlib-whl
python-distro-info
python-docutils
python-egenix-mxdatetime
python-egenix-mxtools
python-extras
python-fixtures
python-funcparserlib
python-gconf
python-gdbm
python-gevent
python-gi
python-gi-cairo
python-glade2
python-gnomekeyring
python-gobject
python-gobject-2
python-gpgme
python-greenlet
python-gst-1.0
python-gtk2
python-html5lib
python-html5lib-whl
python-httplib2
python-ibus
python-imaging
python-jinja2
python-junitxml
python-keyring
python-launchpadlib
python-lazr.restfulclient
python-lazr.uri
python-ldb
python-libxml2
python-lockfile
python-logilab-common
python-lxml
python-markupsafe
python-matplotlib
python-matplotlib-data
python-migrate
python-mimeparse
python-minimal
python-mysqldb
python-nose
python-notify
python-ntdb
python-numpy
python-oauth
python-oauthlib
python-oneconf
python-opencv
python-openssl
python-pam
python-paramiko
python-pbr
python-pexpect
python-pil
python-pip
python-pip-whl
python-piston-mini-client
python-pkg-resources
python-psutil
python-pyatspi
python-pyatspi2
python-pycurl
python-pygame
python-pygments
python-pyparsing
python-qt4
python-qt4-dbus
python-renderpm
python-reportlab
python-reportlab-accel
python-requestbuilder
python-requests
python-requests-whl
python-roman
python-samba
python-scipy
python-scour
python-secretstorage
python-serial
python-setuptools
python-setuptools-whl
python-simplegeneric
python-simplejson
python-sip
python-six
python-six-whl
python-smbc
python-sqlalchemy
python-sqlalchemy-ext
python-subunit
python-support
python-talloc
python-tdb
python-tempita
python-testscenarios
python-testtools
python-tk
python-tornado
python-twisted-bin
python-twisted-core
python-twisted-mail
python-twisted-names
python-twisted-web
python-twisted-words
python-tz
python-ubuntu-sso-client
python-urllib3
python-urllib3-whl
python-virtualenv
python-wadllib
python-webcolors
python-wheel
python-xapian
python-xdg
python-zeitgeist
python-zope.interface
python2.7
python2.7-dev
python2.7-minimal
python3
python3-apparmor
python3-apparmor-click
python3-apport
python3-apt
python3-aptdaemon
python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
python3-autopilot
python3-autopilot-trace
python3-autopilot-vis
python3-brlapi
python3-cairo
python3-chardet
python3-checkbox-ng
python3-checkbox-support
python3-click
python3-commandnotfound
python3-crypto
python3-dateutil
python3-dbus
python3-dbus.mainloop.qt
python3-debian
python3-decorator
python3-defer
python3-distupgrade
python3-evdev
python3-extras
python3-feedparser
python3-fixtures
python3-gdbm:amd64
python3-gi
python3-gi-cairo
python3-httplib2
python3-jinja2
python3-junitxml
python3-libapparmor
python3-louis
python3-lxc
python3-lxml
python3-mako
python3-markupsafe
python3-mimeparse
python3-minimal
python3-oauthlib
python3-oneconf
python3-pil
python3-piston-mini-client
python3-pkg-resources
python3-plainbox
python3-problem-report
python3-psutil
python3-pyatspi
python3-pycurl
python3-pyparsing
python3-pyqt4
python3-requests
python3-sip
python3-six
python3-software-properties
python3-speechd
python3-subunit
python3-testscenarios
python3-testtools
python3-uno
python3-update-manager
python3-urllib3
python3-xdg
python3-xkit
python3-xlib
python3.4
python3.4-minimal
rsync`

Comment: So did you do what the _stack overflow_ post did, and what results did you get.

Comment: I don't consider uninstalling an official package and installing directly from the source a good solution, however, I did try it and the virtualenv keeps failing.

Comment: My exact opinion, as I would never do that. I was only trying to see how far you went with the issue, if you had followed that route...

Comment: Could you please provide details of the problems?

Comment: It seems that the packaging inside virtualenv does not cope with system-wide python-pyparsing package, which is too old.